# Need a mutiple criteria search form for drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Im making a real estate site and need a search form similar to one on this site http://www.weirmanuel.com on the left side

In drupal is their a way to make a search form like this? I need to be able to search by multiple criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try working with [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) and exposed filters.  This will allow you to essentially narrow down all nodes with relevant information and display them in a view ("search results").

Create a new view as you would normally. Add some filters for some fields and click *Expose* in the top right corner of the filter field settings. Then under "Basic settings" change "Exposed form in block" to yes.  Now you will have your "search" block. Go to `admin/build/block` and enable the block.  You can also change which pages the block is visible on.